# can I estimate density function of 2d/3d data with kernel smoothing (e.g. ks package R), or are there better estimation methods

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation, nonparametric-regression

I have a 2d matrix of positive values (non integer), where the values can be thought of intensity at an x,y coordinate indexed by the row and column. I want to estimate a density function across this 2d space and have looked into kernel density estimation.

I understand that kernel density estimation can be used for a similar problem where you have a discrete number of points at different x,y coordinates and want to estimate the density function. I have found packages in R, such as KS, to do this and I would hope to be able to use this package since it appears to work for multidimensional (up to 6) data; I am hoping to extend my method to intensities in a 3d grid space later.

Back to my problem:
It appears that the inputs for a lot of the r packages for 2d kernel smoothing want a two column matrix as the input where each row is an x,y coordinate for an individual point. But, in my data I have non integer values at each point.

does the fact that I have this non integer intensity at each coordinate mean that my data should be treated 3d and not 2d? I'm having a hard time visualising what how/whether kernel smoothing would work in this case- inputting a three column matrix where the columns are x,y,intensity.

Are there any packages and/or methods that I would find useful for my problem where my data is in a 2d or 3d array where the array indexes represent space and the value represents intensity, which I am trying to estimate the density function for.

Please let me know if my questions are not clear.

Thanks

Comment: Find a package that allows you to specify the weights of your points: that's what your "intensities" are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What are the differences between taking a weighted 2d kernel density estimate vs a 3d kernel density estimate?  In page 201 of Elements of Statistical learning there is a diagram of a 3d estimate, where two dimensions represent space and the third represents a velocity. So it seems like a similar case to mine. Does this similarity extend to another dimension; can i use a 4d estimate for data in 3d space with an intensity? I ask this because I have not found any packages for a weighted 3d estimating function